# Video versus Import for video file

Tags: video

For Wolfram Mathematica v13, there are 2 types of importing video:

- Using the `Video[file]`: represents video stored in the given
  file.
- Using the `Import[source]`: imports data from source,    returning a
  Wolfram Language representation of it.

Are they different? In term of performance, are they the same?

Comment: As I remember, the `Video[file]` is a out-of-kernel processing?

Comment: can you clarify me, the difference?

Comment: @NamNguyen they are exactly the same (if you look at the InputForm of both it should match exactly)

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@carlog has answered that, the `InputForm` is the same.

So `Video[file]` and `Import[source]` is the same.